# Why do I get this error? TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am a beginnner and trying to learn python in jupiter notebook. I am trying to practice input and I keep getting this error when I am trying to print the variable **yourname**. I tried changing the name of the variable and still nothing. Even if I do a simple "print(yourname)" I get the same error. Thank you for your patience and help

yourname=input("Please enter your name:")

print(yourname)

age=int(input(("Please enter your age:")))

Comment: You've accidentally assigned a value to the name `print`, so it no longer refers to the built-in function.  Restart the Python interpreter, or do `del print` to clear the problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!